# Is it possible to use the camera without unlocking first?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, camera, lock-screens

Is it possible with Android phones (like with iOS 5) to take photos directly from the lock screen without unlocking first?

Answer (score 5):

With just the stock Android experience, no. That is, until Ice Cream Sandwich is released.

That's not to say that OEMs haven't added their own changes that *do* allow for launching the camera app without unlocking, or perhaps a clever developer making a change to the lockscreen.

Comment: CyanogenMod 7 includes the ability to launch any app from the lockscreen via custom app starter or gestures.

Comment: Yeah, just one day after asking I got the HTC update to Sense 3.0 where there **is** a link to the camera on the lock screen. With Sense 2.x (or other OEM firmware) WidgetLocker is an acceptable workaround (see Bryans answer).

Answer (score 2):

There are apps in android market which provide an alternate lockscreen such as WidgetLock or MagicLocker(Free) through which you could have direct access to camera from the Lock Screen. Also with some custom ROM's based on CyanogenMod, you could add shortcuts to any app on the Lock screen.

Comment: WidgetLocker does this, but as far as I could see from the description in the Android Market, MagicLocker does not.