# How to use camera without unlocking phone? (Jelly Bean on S3)

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, 4.1-jelly-bean, camera

I put Jelly Bean on my Verizon Samsung Galaxy SIII using http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-10-m2.

I know that it should be possible for me to use my camera to take pictures quickly (without unlocking my phone). (See [Is it possible to use the camera without unlocking first?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14942/is-it-possible-to-use-the-camera-without-unlocking-first))

But I haven't figured out how.

I use a 4x4 pattern lock screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use the camera without unlocking first?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14942/is-it-possible-to-use-the-camera-without-unlocking-first)

Comment: @roxan - The other question was talking about 2.2 and the answers were saying things like *this should be fixed in ICS*, while this question is specifically about jelly-bean, so unless there is a specific policy on cross-version duplicates (I've just checked on meta and can't find one) I don't think this is an *exact duplicate*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not positive) that pattern lock and the camera shortcut are mutually exclusive. You can have one but not both, unless you find a custom lockscreen app that supports it.

Comment: see this post, it may help.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52596/how-do-you-skip-the-pin-to-go-directly-to-the-camera-from-the-lock-screen
(I disclose I am the developper of the proposed solution)

Answer (score 1):

WHAT THE MANUAL DOES NOT SAY IS:
**Camera Quick Access = On (Might as well switch this off as it cant work out how to get by the Pattern Recognition for the camera to auto start)**

WHAT IS DOES SAY IS:
**Settings**->**Scroll down to Personal**->**Lock screen**->**Lock screen options**->**Scroll down to Features**->**Camera quick access ON**

***Camera quick access***:
While the screen is locked, and help upright tap and hold the screen, and then
rotate the device to the landscape view to launch the camera (when
the camera shortcut is activated).

See p. 152 of the [Samsung User Manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201209/20120922140937292/GT-I9300_UM_EU_Jellybean_Eng_Rev.1.0_120914_Screen.pdf) from September 2012 Jelly Bean version.

Comment: I couldn't tell from your answer (until I read your label for your edit, which said "Missed out the most important part that to get it to work you have to change from Pattern Recognition") that you're basically saying "You can't do it."  Bummer. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

I do it frequently on a Q700 XOLO. Simply swipe downwards on the lock screen. And then you get to the default camera screen. You can even add another app there if you want to use them without unlocking your phone.